# can a silent push notification be received when the application is open?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to understand if a silent push notification ... {aps: {content-available: 1}} ...  can be received by my iOS application if the user has the app open and is using it.

I have read some docs about it but I am not able to find a definite answer for this.

Anybody?

Comment: Elaborate about what you mean by silent?

Comment: @AlexKoren see {aps: {content-available: 1}}  in my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Official documentation on `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:):

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background.

- `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`: Called only if app is in foreground
- `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`: Called if app is in foreground or background

This applies to all remote notifications also silent ones.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is active/open/in foreground you will receive push notifications in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` of your `AppDelegate` class. This is by default silent. User won't get any info. It's completely on the developer, how to handle it.